# Certificate error installing jspm package from github (caused by wrong cert path??)

Tags: git, jspm

Whilst my development environment works absolutely fine my build server is suffering with errors such as the following... although at some point it was all working fine too!

```
warn Error on lookup for github:aurelia/event-aggregator
     Error: fatal: unable to access 'aurelia/event-aggregator.git/': error setting certificate verify locations:
   CAfile: C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
   CApath: none

err  Error looking up github:aurelia/event-aggregator.
```

I noticed that the `CAfile` path was different to the one on disk (`C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\ssl\certs\ca-bundle.crt`) so copied the ssl folder from `mingw64\` into `mingw64\libexec` and everything started working again.

Is this an appropriate fix?

Here are some of the versions of products I'm running:

```
jspm - 0.16.13
npm - 3.3.10
node - 4.2.1
```

Comment: I had this same issue this morning and did the same thing you did. However, I am not feeling the greatest about this as a fix. Got me going for the time being though.

Comment: This seems like a legitimate issue, have you logged this issue on their github page? I had the same error (the fix also worked for me).

Comment: Interesting  Given you've had similar issues I'll raise it. I've also had dreadful trouble with the aurelia-bundler and dependencies. Makes me wonder whether npm/jspm is worth the trouble or I just handle dependencies manually especially given npm@3 still doesn't solve the Windows path char limit 

Comment: I had this issue too with JSPM 0.16.14. After `npm un jspm -g && npm i jspm -g` I received patched [JSPM 0.16.15](https://github.com/jspm/jspm-cli/releases/tag/0.16.15) with new SystemJS. Now the certificate issue disappeared.

Comment: Thanks @Marcel, 0.16.14 was a problem for me too and 0.16.15 fixed it.

Comment: Some of these Windows-specific errors can be tough to crack.  Consider using [git bash](https://git-for-windows.github.io/) if you can.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that installing new GitExtensions along with Git caused this.

Comment: Yeah, it happened to me when I installed the new version of GitExtensions.

Answer (score 3):

I executed the following command in a command window (run as admin), and it got me up and running. Still not sure this is the right answer, but it felt better than copying the folder:

```
git config --system http.sslcainfo "C:\Program Files\Git\usr\ssl\certs\ca-bundle.crt"
```